# Would a hpc and/or shard mongo cluster solve my system bottle neck?

Tags: vps, cluster, mongodb, node.js

OK so I have an application running on Node.js on the same desktop system that is running my mongo service. I have a certain query that takes about 20 seconds to complete, this entire system interfaces with an phone app so 20 seconds is a but too slow.  I have been reading on [database clusters with mongodb](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mongodb/build-database-clusters-with-mongodb/), [rock clustering](http://www.rocksclusters.org/downloads/2015-05-11-download-rocks-6-2-sidewinder.html) and [arch linux with open mpi](https://www.open-mpi.org/) before I start down any road, would anyone happen to have any input as to which of these solutions would actually lead to a reduced compute time for my Node.js app, that I am running as a service, and the mongodb search? Are there combinations that would effect both? Do I need to implement more than solution? If I was going to buy hardware to act as nodes, in any solution, could I do so on units like [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ComboBundleDetails.aspx?ItemList=Combo.3599017) and still see a performance boost? How powerful/expensive do these client/nodes need to be to actually see an increase in performance? Or do I need to get [9ish virtual private servers?](https://amazonlightsail.com/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=pac_ps_q4&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=lightsail_nb_pac_q42017&sc_content=vps_e&sc_detail=vps&sc_category=lightsail&sc_segment=229758836569&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=US&sc_geo=namer&sc_outcome=pac&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!229758836569!e!!g!!vps&ef_id=WihP3wAABOIQgv@P:20171206201527:s)  Any direction would be appreciated, thanks.

OK let me step more into what this does. I have a proof in concept that I am getting set to move to production, right now it is on my desktop, I know it cannot stay there, so I was seeing what solutions are out there, this is my first time at this.

In a nutshell, this is an indexing service that returns data based off user choices.  The data in question is held by a collection, the system starts by running through the collection, gathering a field and present those contents as a series of choices to the user. The user may select some or none of them. The system then goes through the same collection and sees if any of those choices match what the user was looking for (if they didn't select anything it grabs everything), if it does, it then picks another set of values to present to the user. The system continues in this fashion until it has enough data to present the user the ending data they were looking for. Running through the collection for its third criteria takes about 30ish seconds to complete, but that is because there are 1807 unique ones to date and there are 779 members of the collection being evaluated. That big 1807 pull up and return is what triggered this post and for me to assume that I cannot continue testing with my current equipment/setup and that I need to consider moving towards production environments.

I think that mongodb's hash/shard/cluster setup might work out for me, I just don't know that, because I have never done it. I was just looking to see if there was anyone on this site who has taken a service from development to production and was willing to share what they did, hardware wise, to do so.

Comment: I have no idea what your workload looks like, or what this long query looks like, so I don't have anything to go on for making a suggestion. However, in order to say what kind of resource needs to be changed you'll need to collect data on resource utilization across the stack, regardless of other optimizations. Without that data, I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Clustering in an option (the open-mpi is more for message passing in the processor level). However, before that you need to identify where the bottle neck is. What kind of queries are running? Can you run some benchmarking or tests in the production system? Can you setup a test system to tweak database settings? Are you limited based on hardware power? Maybe you need more memory, SSDs? Again all these depends on the queries. Please also look up general performance recommendation for Mongo service.